# Entity Framework: Ambiguous match found

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 6.1 in asp.net webform project. When I try to add new object into projects, I am getting **Ambiguous match found** exception.
I am using database first approach. I do not any manipulation in created models. I have read some questions about that problem. General cause is same named properties and navigation in class. I did not found any same named property.

Can you tell me what i missed?

Thank you

Code:

```
projects m_NewProject = new projects();
decimal m_CompanyRef = MemberHelperC.getUser().CompanyRef;
DateTime m_EndDate = GeneralHelperC.getCompanyDateTime().AddDays(5);
DateTime m_StartDate = GeneralHelperC.getCompanyDateTime();
customers m_Customer = myEntity.customers.Where(xXx => xXx.CompanyRef == m_CompanyRef).FirstOrDefault();
m_NewProject.ProjectLeadRef = MemberHelperC.getUserID();
m_NewProject.ProjectName = m_ProjectName;
m_NewProject.ProjectStatus = Convert.ToByte(1);
m_NewProject.SourceLangRef = Convert.ToDecimal(comboSourceLang.SelectedValue);
m_NewProject.TargetLangRef = Convert.ToDecimal(comboTargetLang.SelectedValue);
m_NewProject.DomainRef = Convert.ToDecimal(1);
m_NewProject.ProjectYear = GeneralHelperC.getCompanyDateTime()/*DateTime.Now*/.Year;
m_NewProject.EndDate = m_EndDate;
m_NewProject.StartDate = m_StartDate;
m_NewProject.TaskStepNameRef = m_TaskStepNameID;
m_NewProject.CustomerRef = Convert.ToDecimal(m_Customer.RID);
Random m_Random = new Random();
m_NewProject.ProjectUniqueID = m_Random.Next(0, 99999999);
m_NewProject.ProjectTBX = m_Dictionary.RID;
myEntity.projects.Add(m_NewProject);//exception occur this method
myEntity.SaveChanges();
```

Object Class:

```
public partial class projects
{
    public projects()
    {
        this.projectnotes = new HashSet<projectnotes>();
        this.projectpriceoffers = new HashSet<projectpriceoffers>();
        this.projectreferencedoc = new HashSet<projectreferencedoc>();
        this.projects1 = new HashSet<projects>();
        this.taskstepexceptions = new HashSet<taskstepexceptions>();
        this.tbxrelation = new HashSet<tbxrelation>();
        this.tmproject = new HashSet<tmproject>();
        this.tmrelation = new HashSet<tmrelation>();
        this.wizardprojecttasks = new HashSet<wizardprojecttasks>();
        this.works = new HashSet<works>();
    }

    public decimal RID { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public decimal ProjectStatus { get; set; }
    public decimal ProjectLeadRef { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public int ProjectYear { get; set; }
    public int ProjectUniqueID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> ParentProjectRef { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> TMXHeaderRef { get; set; }
    public decimal SourceLangRef { get; set; }
    public decimal TargetLangRef { get; set; }
    public decimal DomainRef { get; set; }
    public decimal TaskStepNameRef { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> ProjectTBX { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> CustomerRef { get; set; }

    public virtual customers customers { get; set; }
    public virtual domainname domainname { get; set; }
    public virtual language language { get; set; }
    public virtual language language1 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<projectnotes> projectnotes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<projectpriceoffers> projectpriceoffers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<projectreferencedoc> projectreferencedoc { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<projects> projects1 { get; set; }
    public virtual projects projects2 { get; set; }
    public virtual projectstatus projectstatus1 { get; set; }
    public virtual tasknames tasknames { get; set; }
    public virtual tbxdictionary tbxdictionary { get; set; }
    public virtual tmxheaderinterface tmxheaderinterface { get; set; }
    public virtual users users { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<taskstepexceptions> taskstepexceptions { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<tbxrelation> tbxrelation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<tmproject> tmproject { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<tmrelation> tmrelation { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<wizardprojecttasks> wizardprojecttasks { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<works> works { get; set; }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. There is a really ambiguous in my code. **CustomerStatus** really dublicated.

I think Entity Framework team should improve Ambiguous match found exception details. I have more than 90 tables and very hard to debugging...

Exception occure of these code:

```
public partial class customers
{
    public enum CustomerStatusEnum : long
    {
        Closed = 3,
        Open = 1,
        Potential = 2
    }

    public CustomerStatusEnum CustomerStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return (CustomerStatusEnum)Status;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So how is `CustomerStatus` duplicated here?

Comment: Yes, I asked my self how? :) This is partial class of `customers`. Actually `customer` entity automatic generated by Entity Framework and same time I add same named properties `CustomerStatus` which partial class. I hope, I can explain.

Comment: ahh, I see. Maybe if you include the relevant part of the other partial class, it might be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure there are no same named property somewhere with different casing? It compiles as case sensative, but executes as case insensitive, so even a few capital letters difference in a same name property could cause a Ambiguous match found exception.

Comment: I have searched all entities related to **projects** but i did not found any same named property.
Is there a any method analyse to ambiguous match found exception?

Comment: I searched for a while, but did not find any code that reflects on all propertyname.

Comment: I have download EF source code and referance to my project. I will try to debug :)

Comment: So how did it play out? Did you find a solution?

Comment: I could not build EF source code in the same solution. When I try to compile, I am getting "System.Data not found". Actually very bored that problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem:

I had a table named `service` linked to the table `order`.
Inside my partial class `order`, I was using a property called `Service`.

```
//Auto generated:
public virtual service service { get; set; }

//My custom property (Shortned, there was a big String.Format inside):
public String Service { get { return service.ds_name; }}
```

Case insensitive. :/

TL;DR: `Property inside partial class with the same name, but with diffferent caps.`